# How to make ul extend past parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with a set width and height and the overflow set to auto. Inside, there is an unordered list with content that causes the div to scroll.

The problem is that the list itself does not extend past the container div. So when I try to add padding to the right side of the list, it doesn't work properly:

[image]

[image]

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tgjbou6/5/) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `float: left` to your `ul` menu element.

If you float your `ul` within the `.container`, the item will no longer expand to the width of the parent.

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4tgjbou6/7/)

You can achieve this with adding: `display: inline-block` too, instead floating it.

Comment: I don't know the deep reason, but I explained that setting `display: inline-block` or floating items they will not expand to the width of parent but will go past their container dimensions if needed. Please share if know know the what goes 'behind the scenes`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `white-space: nowrap;`

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    //Remove white-space
   // white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/4tgjbou6/8/)